# PLSQL IF/ELSE function to check XML value

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a function that will take an entry (ID) and then check the relevant XMLTYPE field for a particular XML value and take action based on the result however I am having some difficulty in putting all the pieces together. I have the following select statement which works to select the XML value I am looking for:

```
select x.xmldata.extract('//Fc_curstage/text()').getStringVal()
from test_data  x
where id = 149;
```

and the function I have so far is:

```
create or replace
function get_xmlstatus
    (p_stage in NUMBER)
    return VARCHAR2 is
    v_stage varchar2(20);

    begin
    return varchar2
      IF v_cur_stg = 'INITIAL' THEN
      -- Create new record in stage
    v_stage := 'INITIAL 1';

    ELSIF v_cur_stg = 'RETURNED' THEN
      -- Remove any associated records from the stage
    v_stage := 'Returned 2';
    ELSE
      -- this should raise exception
    v_stage := 'Blank Expected 3';
    END IF;
```

I am not sure where I need to declare that:

```
v_cur_stg:=x.xmldata.extract('//Fc_curstage/text()').getStringVal();
```

or where I need to include the select statement so that the function knows what to do with the ID that is being passed into the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create or replace function get_xmlstatus (p_stage in NUMBER)
  return VARCHAR2 is

  v_cur_stage varchar2(20);
  v_stage varchar2(20);
 begin

   select x.xmldata.extract('//Fc_curstage/text()').getStringVal()
   into v_cur_stg
    from test_data  x
   where id = p_stage; --149;   


   IF v_cur_stg = 'INITIAL' THEN
      -- Create new record in stage
    v_stage := 'INITIAL 1';

    ELSIF v_cur_stg = 'RETURNED' THEN
      -- Remove any associated records from the stage
    v_stage := 'Returned 2';
    ELSE
      -- this should raise exception
    v_stage := 'Blank Expected 3';
    END IF;

    Return v_stage;
 End;
```